# MvcMusicStore tutorial - View cannot resolve model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and following the [MVC 4 Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-fundamentals), since one doesn't seem to exist for the latest version.

I've gotten to the point in the tutorial where a StoreIndexViewModel and related controller and view have been added.

When I run it though, and hit the Store page, it's throwing the following:

**Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'genres' and no extension method 'genres' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Users\abourke\dev\csdev\Training\MVC5\MvcMusicStore\MvcMusicStore\Views\Store\Index.cshtml   9   23  MvcMusicStore
**

Here's the StoreIndexViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMusicStore.ViewModels
{
    public class StoreIndexViewModel
    {
        public int NumberOfGenres { get; set; }
        public List<string> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Index() method of the related StoreController:

```
//
// GET: /Store/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Create a list of genres
    var genres = new List<string> { "Rock", "Jazz", "Country", "Pop", "Disco" };

    // Create our view model
    var viewModel = new StoreIndexViewModel
    {
        NumberOfGenres = genres.Count(),
        Genres = genres
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And finally the Index.chstml view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.StoreIndexViewModel> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Genres";
}

<h2>Browse Genres</h2>

<p>Select from @Model.genres</p>

<ul>

    @foreach (string genreName in Model.Genres)
    {
        <li>
            @genreName
        </li>
    }

</ul>
```

Comment: It should be capitalized: `@Model.Genres` instead of  `@Model.genres`. Or is it just typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, your view is typed with different type, should be

```
@model MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.StoreIndexViewModel
```

At second, I assume the "Select from..." string should look like this:

```
<p>Select from @Model.NumberOfGenres</p>
```

Comment: Argh. I had made the first two hours ago, but must not have built it between changing and testing.